# Filter JSON results by multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, filter

I'm creating a Google Maps filter, and I want to get locations from my JSON with multiple criteria and in future add more filter fields, to allow searching for locations in my map.

I created a test Fiddle for getting all locations, but in topics found only one specific criteria, to search for.

Now it works only with country, but I wanted to make to search with all filter fields.

```js
var JSON = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhcarlosweb/google-maps-multi-filter-jquery/master/stores.json";

$.getJSON(JSON, function(stores) {
  $.each(stores, function(i, store) {
    var title = store.name;
    var country = store.location.country.name;
    var city = store.location.city.name;
    var district = store.location.district.name;
    var type = store.type.name;

    $("#results").append(title + "<br>" + country + "<br>" + city + "<br>" + district + "<br>" + type + "<br><br>");
  });
});

$("#filter").click(function() {
  $("#results").text("");

  var formObj = {};
  var inputs = $('#mapFilter').serializeArray();
  $.each(inputs, function(i, input) {
    if (input.value != "") {
      formObj[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  });
  if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(formObj).length !== 0) {
    getJSON(formObj);
  }
});

function getJSON(values) {
  var city = values.filter_country;
  console.log(city);

  $.getJSON(JSON, function(stores) {
    $.each(stores, function(i, store) {
      if (store.location.country.name == city) {
        var title = store.name;
        $("#results").append(title + "<br><br>");
        return;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Filter
<form id="mapFilter">
  <input type="text" name="filter_key" id="keyword" />
  <select name="filter_country">
    <option>Brasil</option>
    <option>Estados Unidos</option>
  </select>
  <select name="filter_city">
    <option>Dighton</option>
    <option>Goiânia</option>
    <option>Nova Friburgo</option>
    <option>Petrópolis</option>
    <option>Fortaleza</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="filter_district" id="district" />
</form>
<button id="filter">Filter</button>

<br /><br /> Locations
<div id="results"></div>
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/shmjLo4d/46/)

Comment: what is your exact requirement?

Comment: @NegiRox that it filters by multiple criteria, for example, city and name

Comment: You're not filtering JSON (which is a string format); you're filtering objects in an array. If you search for "filtering array of objects by multiple properties" you'll likely find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from comments on my post, I found solution for my problem. after marker array push and filter form submit, filters my markers by this code

where
`markers` is pushed markers from JSON
`filter` is `formObj` from fiddle

```
locations = markers.filter(function(item) {
  for (var key in filter) {
    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(locations);
```

Comment: or `markers.filter(x => x.property === ...)`